# Create RESTful Services API in PHP

Tags: php, api, rest

I'm new to this, I've been trying to work on the code below.

```
<?php
require_once("Rest.inc.php");

class API extends REST {

    public $data = "";

    const DB_SERVER = "localhost";
    const DB_USER = "root";
    const DB_PASSWORD = "";
    const DB = "users";

    private $db = NULL;

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();              // Init parent contructor
        $this->dbConnect();                 // Initiate Database connection
    }

    /*
     *  Database connection 
    */
    private function dbConnect(){
        $this->db = mysql_connect(self::DB_SERVER,self::DB_USER,self::DB_PASSWORD);
        if($this->db)
            mysql_select_db(self::DB,$this->db);
    }

    /*
     * Public method for access api.
     * This method dynmically call the method based on the query string
     *
     */
    public function processApi(){
        $func = strtolower(trim(str_replace("/","",$_REQUEST['rquest'])));
        if((int)method_exists($this,$func) > 0)
            $this->$func();
        else
            $this->response('',404);                // If the method not exist with in this class, response would be "Page not found".
    }

    /* 
     *  Simple login API
     *  Login must be POST method
     *  email : <USER EMAIL>
     *  pwd : <USER PASSWORD>
     */

    private function login(){
        // Cross validation if the request method is POST else it will return "Not Acceptable" status
        if($this->get_request_method() != "POST"){
            $this->response('',406);
        }

        $email = $this->_request['email'];
        $password = $this->_request['pwd'];

        // Input validations
        if(!empty($email) and !empty($password)){
            if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
                $sql = mysql_query("SELECT user_id, user_fullname, user_email FROM users WHERE user_email = '$email' AND user_password = '".md5($password)."' LIMIT 1", $this->db);
                if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0){
                    $result = mysql_fetch_array($sql,MYSQL_ASSOC);

                    // If success everythig is good send header as "OK" and user details
                    $this->response($this->json($result), 200);
                }
                $this->response('', 204);   // If no records "No Content" status
            }
        }

        // If invalid inputs "Bad Request" status message and reason
        $error = array('status' => "Failed", "msg" => "Invalid Email address or Password");
        $this->response($this->json($error), 400);
    }

    private function users(){   
        // Cross validation if the request method is GET else it will return "Not Acceptable" status
        if($this->get_request_method() != "GET"){
            $this->response('',406);
        }
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT user_id, user_fullname, user_email FROM users WHERE user_status = 1", $this->db);
        if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0){
            $result = array();
            while($rlt = mysql_fetch_array($sql,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
                $result[] = $rlt;
            }
            // If success everythig is good send header as "OK" and return list of users in JSON format
            $this->response($this->json($result), 200);
        }
        $this->response('',204);    // If no records "No Content" status
    }

    private function deleteUser(){
        // Cross validation if the request method is DELETE else it will return "Not Acceptable" status
        if($this->get_request_method() != "DELETE"){
            $this->response('',406);
        }
        $id = (int)$this->_request['id'];
        if($id > 0){                
            mysql_query("DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id = $id");
            $success = array('status' => "Success", "msg" => "Successfully one record deleted.");
            $this->response($this->json($success),200);
        }else
            $this->response('',204);    // If no records "No Content" status
    }

    /*
     *  Encode array into JSON
    */
    private function json($data){
        if(is_array($data)){
            return json_encode($data);
        }
    }
}

// Initiiate Library

$api = new API;
$api->processApi();
?>
```

You can find more about code [here](http://www.9lessons.info/2012/05/create-restful-services-api-in-php.html)
When I run it through POST on RESTClient with URL: `http://localhost/rest/login/`, it says-

**Notice**:  Undefined index: email in **C:\xampp\htdocs\rest\api.php** on line **55**
**Notice**:  Undefined index: pwd in **C:\xampp\htdocs\rest\api.php** on line **56**
{"status":"Failed","msg":"Invalid Email address or Password"}

But when I change it to URL: `http://localhost/rest/api.php/login`
Error says-

**Notice**:  Undefined index: rquest in **C:\xampp\htdocs\rest\api.php** on line **35**

Please help to correct the error.

Comment: Please stop using mysql_ functions, they are depreciated and a security risk as you aren't escaping your variables. You should use PDO instead.